# Grep Multiple word From string in python

Tags: python, string

String Format and the expected result..

> ```
> >>>a = 'afd fdfe {a.b.c} fdferef {c.d.f}dfefe dfefffe + fdfef {}'
> >>>{a.b.c},{c.d.f},{}
> ```

I tried with the following code.And the result is...

> ```
> >>>re.search(r'{.*.}',a).group()
> >>>{a.b.c} fdferef {c.d.f}dfefe dfefffe + fdfef {}'
> ```

Another

> ```
> >>>re.search(r'{.?*.}',a).group()
> >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
>      return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
>      raise error, v # invalid expression
>    sre_constants.error: multiple repeat
> ```

Comment: `print(*re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', a), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the meaning of `.`, `*`, and `?`.

`.` is a metacharacter which matches a single character (for example, `a` or `.` or `{`, or sometimes - but not usually - newline).

`*` is a metacharacter which repeats the previous regular expression zero or more times. (For example, `.*` matches the empty string, or everything, possibly excepting newlines.)

`?` as a lone metacharacter repeats the previous regular expression zero or one times. (For example, `.?` matches no character, or one character, again possibly excepting newlines).

There are also combinations; for example, `*?` says to repeat zero or more times, but prefer as few repetitions as possible ("non-greedy" or "stingy" matching).

Round parentheses are used for grouping; if you want to use `.group()`, you should probably use parentheses around the matches you want to pull out.

With that out of the way, try

```
re.findall(r'(\{[^{}]*\})', a)
```

where `[^{}]` matches a single character which is not a curly brace, and the backslash escapes the curly braces which are otherwise also a regex metacharacter for specifying a particular number of repetitions (for example, `.{3}` matches three arbitrary characters, and `\?{5,}` matches five or more literal question marks).

If you want to loop over the matches, perhaps prefer the generator `re.finditer()` over `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ' 45 54 '
True
b = ' 45'
True
c = '45 '
True 
d = '45'
False
e = 'er 44 434'
False
```

Want to find and check space before words and afer words

Comment: ' ' in a[0] or ' ' in a[-1]